# How to make all i's and j's dotless, glyph substitution

Tags: fonts, xetex

I just learned about the existence of dotless i's and j's- `\i` and `\j`, which happens to be how I write them out by hand. Would there be a way of making all occurrences of both appear dotless with some kind of character/glyph substitution or redefinition and not as hundreds of control sequences? TeX Gyre Adventor has both- unicodes 0131 and 0237, from the doc. The `fontspec` package says the `DTLS` feature, "Dotless Forms", is an unsupported OpenType feature. TeX by Topic doesn't seem to have what I'm looking for. I'm using XeLaTeX.

Comment: Why do you need to replace all occurences of `i` and `j` by their dotless versions? When used with LaTeX accents or in accented Unicode characters the dot should be removed automatically.

Comment: Do you want to do this in math or in text?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using XeTeX it's quite easy to substitute all text `i` and `j` with `ı` and `ȷ`.  You can use the powerful Teckit mapping engine.

Create the following file `dotless.map` (make sure it's UTF-8).  This is the default `tex-text` map file with a dotless conversion added.

```
LHSName "dotted"
RHSName "dotless"
pass(Unicode)
; replace dotted i and j with dotless versions
"i" > "ı"
"j" > "ȷ"
; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D           <>  U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>  U+2014  ; --- -> em dash

U+0027          <>  U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027   <>  U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
U+0022           >  U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

U+0060          <>  U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060   <>  U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060   <>  U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060   <>  U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question
```

Compile this to a `.tec` file with the following command:

```
teckit_compile -u  dotless.map -o dotless.tec
```

Now you can load any font which has the dotless glyphs with this mapping file and all the `i`s and `j`s will be dotless. If you load the `mathspec` package you can also substitute the math `i` and `j` too.

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=dotless]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\dottedfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont(Latin)[Mapping=dotless]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
This is a document in which all the `i' and `j'  characters are dotless. 

This is not a joke or a jibe, so jump in and join the high jinks!

{\dottedfont But if this gives you the jitters you can junk the dotless version.}

You can even do it with math:

\[
i = j
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I'd upvote again for the text if I could. :-) Good choice of words to illustrate the letters.

Comment: Without dots I read them as "This is not a yoke or a yibe so yump in and yoin the high yinks"

Comment: Is that change only cosmetic? So, if I copy the text from the PDF, will it contain the original basic ‘i’s?

Comment: @matj1 No, it's not cosmetic. It literally replaces the dotted 'i' with the the undotted 'ı'.

Answer (score 15):

In LuaTeX you can define your own font feature for that matter.  If you want the substitution to only apply in text or math mode, just comment out the corresponding statements in the definition below.  I also defined the reverse mapping, so you can recover the dotted versions in dotless mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "dotlessij",
    type = "substitution",
    data = {
        -- Text mode
        i = "ı",
        j = "ȷ",
        ı = "i",
        ȷ = "j",
        -- Math mode
         = "",
         = "",
         = "",
         = "",
    }
}
```

```
\end{luacode*}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[RawFeature={+dotlessij}]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[RawFeature={+dotlessij}]
\begin{document}
i, j, \i, \j

$i, j, \i, \j$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: From the text, I understand that it is a font feature, so it is just cosmetic and shouldn't affect the underlying text. The other option would be that it would switch the underlying text and then render it normally. But, If I compile it and copy the text from the PDF, I get “ı, ȷ, j, j
, , , ”, which is strange. The first line has the characters switched, but the second doesn't. What is up with that?

Comment: The problem was that my editor for LaTeX (Overleaf) doesn't support the italic characters. But, then, it looks like a font feature, but it affects the underlying text. Why is that?